# Why is this matrix necessarily positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

A recently asked question here was solved with the claim that any symmetric square matrix $M$ of the following form is positive definite:

- All of the off-diagonal elements are the same positive integer $k$.
- Each diagonal element is a positive integer $n_i \gt k$.  The diagonal elements may or may not be equal to one another.

The matrix arises as the product of a particular incidence matrix with its transpose. Why is a matrix of this form positive definite?

Comment: Thanks, but in this case positive definite was essential to the proof.

Comment: It is positive definite because it is the sum of a positive definite matrix (namely, the positive diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(n_1-k,\ n_2-k\ldots)$) and a positive semidefinite matrix (whose elements are all equal to $k$).

Comment: @user1551 Elegant argument.  I was messing around with row-echelon form.  You ought to post this as an answer, I think.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo We needed to know the matrix is positive definite in order to get control over the rank of the incidence matrix.

Comment: @user1551 I agree, it's answer time!  Ready to upvote it b/c you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is positive definite because it is the sum of a positive definite matrix (namely, the positive diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(n_1−k,\ n_2-k,\ldots)$) and a positive semidefinite matrix (whose elements are all equal to $k$).